# Why async keyword function without await keyword in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I saw many people's code use `async` keyword in a function without an `await` keyword in the function body. Even some official flutter example code do this. I have no idea why. What is the point? Is this a mistake or having a purpose?

Normally, I just remove the `async` keyword from those code and everything will run without any problems. Can some dart expert clarify that if there is a purpose for a function which has the `async` keyword but NO `await` keyword? Or is this just their mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` is sometimes used to simplify code.

Here are some examples:

```
Future<int> f1() async => 1;
Future<int> f1() => Future.value(1);

Future<void> f2() async {
  throw Error();
}
Future<void> f2() {
  return Future.error(Error());
}
```

Comment: Several things. You can be forced to return a Future if you implements a method returning a Future. You can use `f1` as value for something needing a `Future<int> Function()` (for instance `void myAwesomeFunction(Future<int> Function() provider)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I finally understand why some people do this. I found many code can remove async keyword safely. I think they just put there in case or forget to remove it. For example, I saw some people did `Future<int> f() async => anotherFunction()` and the `anotherFunction()` does return a Future. But they still have useless `async` in the f() function. I can see why they tried to add async at the first place. 
*(Btw, Sorry, I deleted my first comment just a few seconds before your reply since I understood at that time. If I knew you would reply, I would keep it. )*

Answer (score 1):

According to [official Dart Language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#asynchrony-support), `async` executes synchronously until it finds `await` keyword  :

> Note: Although an async function might perform time-consuming operations, it doesn’t wait for those operations. Instead, the async function executes only until it encounters its first await expression ([details](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/newsletter/20170915.md#synchronous-async-start)). Then it returns a Future object, resuming execution only after the await expression completes.